# If $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a finite discrete set, then $A=\prod_i A_i$, where $A_i$ contains a unique maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Lemma 6.2 of Waterhouse's Introduction to Affine Group Schemes has a Lemma stating, for $k$ a field,

> Let $A$ be a finite dimensional, commutative $k$ algebra. Then $A$ is a finite direct product of algebras $A_i$, each of which has a unique maximal ideal consisting of nilpotent elements.

Proof: Using the fact that $A$ is finite dimensional, Waterhouse first shows that every prime ideal of $A$ is in fact maximal, and that there are only finitely many primes. Since each is maximal, it follows that in the Zariski topology $Z(P)=\{P\}$, so each point is closed. Hence $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a finite discrete set.

I understand this, but I lose him when he then immediately states, that hence $A=\prod_i A_i$, (without mention of what $A_i$ is), and that the unique prime in $A_i$ is maximal, and its elements must be nilpotent.

I know that since $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is finite and discrete, each $Z(P_i)=\{P_i\}$ is clopen, hence $Z(P_i)=Z(e_i)$ for an idempotent $e_i\in A$. Does $\operatorname{Spec}(A)=Z(e_1)\sqcup\cdots\sqcup Z(e_m)$ imply somehow that $A\simeq Ae_1\times\cdots\times Ae_m$? I know that if $e$ is an idempotent, $\operatorname{Spec}(A)=Z(e)\sqcup Z(1-e)$ implies $A\simeq Ae\times A(1-e)$, but if there are more than two clopen sets, I'm not sure how it extends. For instance, is $\operatorname{Spec}(A)=Z(e_1)\sqcup Z(e_2)\sqcup Z(e_3)=Z(e_1)\sqcup Z(e_2e_3)$, then we have $1-e_1=e_2e_3$, so that
$$
A\simeq Ae_1\times A(1-e_1)\simeq Ae_1\times Ae_2e_3.
$$

But it doesn't seem like $Ae_2e_3\simeq Ae_2\times Ae_3$.

**Edit** Would it be fair to say 
$$
\operatorname{Spec}(A)=Z(P_1)\sqcup\cdots\sqcup Z(P_m)\simeq\operatorname{Spec}(Ae_1)\sqcup\cdots\sqcup\operatorname{Spec}(Ae_m)\simeq\operatorname{Spec}(\prod_{i}Ae_i)
$$
so that $A\simeq \prod_i Ae_i$ since $\operatorname{Spec}$ reflects isomorphism as an equivalence of categories?

Comment: Your geometric argument works and is a great approach.  A coproduct (disjoint union) of affine schemes turns into a product of rings.

Comment: @D_S Thanks, I'm familiar with sheaves and whatnot, so it was helpful to read your answer.

Comment: If there is an idempotent, you can split the ring in two and then do induction

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks, I tried that in the body but couldn't see how to continue to split the ring into rings containing unique maximal ideals after the first step.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a ring whose prime spectrum $X$ is finite and discrete. Then $R$ must be a semilocal ring with maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_1, ... , \mathfrak m_n$, with no prime ideals.

I think the geometric argument you suggested will work.  I don't know how much algebraic geometry you know, so I'll state the relevant results .  Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $Y$ be the space of prime ideals of $A$.  To each open set $U$ of $Y$ is associated a certain ring $\mathcal O_Y(U)$.  In particular, $\mathcal O_Y(\emptyset)$ is the zero ring, and $\mathcal O_Y(Y)$ can be canonically identified with $A$ itself.  To each inclusion of open sets $U \subseteq V$ is associated a certain ring homomorphism $\mathcal O_Y(V) \rightarrow \mathcal O_Y(U)$ denoted by $s \mapsto s|_U$.  If $U_i$ is an open cover of $Y$, then the sequence of abelian groups

$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow \prod\limits_i \mathcal O_Y(U_i) \rightarrow \prod\limits_{i,j} \mathcal O_Y(U_i \cap U_j)$$

is exact, where the last map is $(s_i ) \mapsto (s_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} - s_j|_{U_i \cap U_j})$.  In particular, if you have a disjoint open cover $U_i$ of $Y$, then you get an isomorphism of $A$ with the product ring $\prod\limits_i \mathcal O_Y(U_i)$.  Finally, if $\mathfrak p \in Y$, then as you run $U$ over smaller and smaller open neighborhoods of $\mathfrak p$, you can pass to the direct limit of the corresponding rings $\mathcal O_Y(U)$ to obtain a local ring $\mathcal O_{Y,\mathfrak p}$, which is nothing more than $A_{\mathfrak p}$, the localization of $A$ at $\mathfrak p$.

You can apply all this to your situation: $X$ is the disjoint union of $n$ open sets $\{\mathfrak m_i\}$, so the sheaf condition tells you that the restriction maps $R= \mathcal O_X(X) \rightarrow \mathcal O_X(\{\mathfrak m_i\}) = R_{\mathfrak m_i}$ induce an isomorphism of $R$ with $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n R_{\mathfrak m_i}$.  Each $R_{\mathfrak m_i}$ is local with nilpotent nonunits.

Without algebraic geometry, you can still probably argue directly that the map $r \mapsto (r/1, ... , r/1)$ defines an isomorphism

$$R \rightarrow \prod\limits_{i=1}^n R_{\mathfrak m_i}$$

but I can't immediately see a clean proof.  I'll try it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

All right, I think I see how to use the direct approach now.  Since $Z(e_i) = Z(P_i)$, then $\sqrt{(e_i)} = \sqrt{P_i} = P_i$.  Since $A$ is Noetherian, then $(e_i) = P_i^{r_i}$ for some $r_i$, and since the ideals $P_i$ are pairwise comaximal, then so are $P_i^{r_i}$ (c.f., exercise 1.13 in Atiyah-MacDonald).  (One can also show this directly: for $i \neq j$ we have
$$
Z((e_i) + (e_j)) = Z(e_i) \cap Z(e_j) = \varnothing
$$
so $(e_i) + (e_j) = 1$.)  We also have
\begin{align*}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Nil}{Nil}
(e_1 \cdots e_m) = \prod_i P_i^{r_i} \subseteq \bigcap_i P_i = \Nil(A)
\end{align*}
which implies that $e_1 \cdots e_m$ is nilpotent.  Then $(e_1 \cdots e_m)^r = 0$ for some $r$, but since each $e_i$ is idempotent, then
$$
0 = e_1^r \cdots e_m^r = e_1 \cdots e_m \, .
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
A \cong \frac{A}{(0)} \cong \frac{A}{(e_1) \cdots (e_m)} \cong \frac{A}{(e_1)} \times \cdots \times \frac{A}{(e_m)} \cong \frac{A}{P_1^{r_1}} \times \cdots \times \frac{A}{P_m^{r_m}}
\end{align*}
by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Each factor $A_i := A/P_i^{r_i}$ is local with maximal ideal $P_i/P_i^{r_i}$.

Comment: I was originally trying to do something like this, but I don't see how I've shown the idempotents are a complete set of orthogonal idempotents? If $e_ie_j=0$, shouldn't we have $\operatorname{Spec}(A)=Z(0)=Z(e_ie_j)=Z(e_i)\cup Z(e_j)$, but this doesn't seem right if there are more than two primes in the spectrum. It's also not clear to me how they sum to $1$ if there are more than two points.

Comment: @JoieHwang Edited, and hopefully correct now!

Answer (score 1):

I don't yet see how to get the direct approach to work, so here's an answer that uses the theory of Artinian rings. This is basically just Theorem 8.7 in Atiyah-MacDonald, but I'll try to add a little extra exposition.

First note that since $A$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra, then it is Artinian: each ideal is a vector subspace, so the length of a descending chain of ideals is bounded by $\operatorname{dim}_k(A)$.  Now we apply the aforementioned theorem:

**Theorem.** *Every Artinian ring $A$ can be written as a finite direct product of local Artinian rings.*

*Proof.* One can show that every prime ideal is maximal in an Artinian ring and that there are only finitely many maximal ideals (c.f., Prop 8.1 and 8.3 in A-M; Waterhouse has already showed this in your particular case).  Denote these by $\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak{m}} \m_1, \ldots, \m_n$.  Then
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Nil}{Nil}
\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}
\Nil(A) = \bigcap_{\substack{\p \trianglelefteq A\\ \text{prime}}} \p = \bigcap_{\substack{\m \trianglelefteq A\\ \text{maximal}}} \m = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \m_i \, .
$$
By Prop. 8.4 the nilradical is nilpotent, so $\Nil(A)^r = 0$ for some $r$, hence
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \m_i^r \subseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n \m_i^r = \Nil(A)^r = 0 \, .
$$
Since the ideals $\m_i^r$ are pairwise comaximal, then $A \cong \prod_{i=1}^n A/\m_i^r$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Each $A/\m_i^r$ is a local Artinian ring with maximal ideal $\m_i/\m_i^r$.  That $\m_i/\m_i^r$ consists of nilpotent elements follows from the fact that prime and maximal ideals coincide, since this implies that the nilradical and Jacobson radical ($=\m_i/\m_i^r$) are equal.